# How to create custom unique validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to create custom unique validation.

There is three elements of type, ['top', 'middle',bottom'].

Name have just three of them.
How should I create validation for this?

```
  validates :name, uniqueness: {scope: [:type]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks good to me. Just, you don't need an array because you scope for just one value.

```
validates :name, uniqueness: { scope: :type }
```

Comment: My pleasure Sir :)